# Changed the timezone but still getting UTC

Tags: laravel

I have changed the timezone for my laravel app to be `Africa\Cairo`, and i changed this in the app.php file

```
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Timezone
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the default timezone for your application, which
| will be used by the PHP date and date-time functions. We have gone
| ahead and set this to a sensible default for you out of the box.
|
*/

'timezone'        => 'Africa/Cairo',
```

but when i check in prodduction the time zone using `Carbon::now()`, i get the timezone is UTC

How can i set the timezone in Carbon

Comment: This works for me, do you have any value in app/config/local/app.php that clash the value in app/config/app.php ? Also yo have tried to print something like this? `$user->created_at->tmiezoneName;`  ?

Comment: when i print `Carbon::now() ` i get UTC timezone in the returned array, i don't know may be it's overwritten somewhere in the app

Answer (score 2):

make sure you clear the cache, write this in your terminal (in the project directory):

```
php artisan config:cache
```

then start the project again to see the changes

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `Carbon::now('Africa/Cairo')`.
That should get you the correct time.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I want to set that in all my application, so that when new record added created_at added with the right timezone

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Cairo'); // set your default timezone
$date = Carbon::createFromFormat('F j, Y g:i:a', date('F j, Y g:i:a'));

dd($date->format('F j, Y g:i:a')); //November 27, 2020 7:00:pm
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Carbon::now()->timezone('Australia/Sydney')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```